# Database table separation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a web site in which users can post different type content. For example images, videos, text and so on. My question is there any benefits in separating each type of post in separate table like the picture below.
[image: picture]

I am doing this separation because images and videos urls will be stored and for the text column of type text is used. Is there any better approach.

Comment: Why they linked by `uuid` but not `post_id`? Can they be linked to several posts with same uuid?

Comment: Yes they are now connected with post_id this is old photo. Fields are changed but the schema is the same

Comment: It's your decision and your business logic. If there is not any difference - merge them to some `post_media`. Add `type` column if you need to process them different ways. But if this difference is important, and in future you can to add some particular fields and methods(ex: views for videos or face_area for selfies) - leave them as is.

Comment: You also need to consider how you will be rerieving posts in your code. Joining multiple tables each time you want to show a list of posts would result in messy code and slower performance. Similarly to insert a post you will need conditional logic to work out which table to insert it into.